# How to create Dynamic table in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

We want call a Stored procedure which returns 4 tables in my Stored procedure.To create dynamic table in my sp I am using **OPENROWSET**. While executing my new sp i am getting **Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.** exception.

When I debugged my code the dymanic table whic is getting created is having columns for the first table only.

Edit 1:

Create table #temp 'SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET( 'SQLNCLI', 'DRIVER={SQL Server};', 'EXEC spreturninngfourtable')

Insert into #temp 'EXEC
 spreturninngfourtable'

Comment: I found similar question, hope you find it helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705045/dynamic-table-names-in-stored-procedure-function

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @wei_dba I had appended my code....